# Zeoslib in Delphi xe5 installation

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe5, zeos

I am trying to install zeoslib in Delphi xe5 with no success.

I keep getting a `Ambiguous overloaded call to Char Inset` error when I try to compile or build the project.

I use zeoslib to connect to remote MySQL databases with my desktop application.

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit and Delphi XE 5.

Note:
I have not found any information on how to install it in XE 5, so any help will be appreciated.

The site's main link as i understand is http://zeoslib.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Found the answer.

the installer should be downloaded from the site as explained here:http://zeoslib.sourceforge.net/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=4955

After downloading Install into IDE gives an error that a package: `ZFastCode in '..\..\src\core\ZFastCode.pas' does not exist`
Remove that line from the unit as explained here:http://zeoslib.sourceforge.net/viewtopic.php?t=10886&p=25765

Build and compile and install then you should be ready to go.